# FragmentTransaction.add() parameters issues

Tags: android, addition, resolve

I want to show a simple fragment once a button is clicked... seemingly android doesn't want to let me because every question and answer and tutorial I checked for this issue didn't fix anything so I hope you guys can help me since this small error is driving me nuts :

```js
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                contact fragment = new contact();
                ft.add(R.id.MyFragment, fragment);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
```

the issue is coming from the line :
(Cannot resolve method 'add(int, org.zewde.futuristiclivewallpapers.contact)') even though I have the contact.class (which is the class extending Fragment)...

```js
ft.add(R.id.MyFragment, fragment);
```

In my activity_home.xml I have a linearlayout:

```js
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyFragment"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I'm thinking it's a problem with the imports I've made in my main activity, maybe?

```js
import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;
```

Here's a screenshot of my directory:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqSpp.png)

---

Update: Here is my contact.class, I haven't added any codes to it yet...

```js
package org.zewde.futuristiclivewallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link contact.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link contact#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class contact extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment contact.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static contact newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        contact fragment = new contact();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public contact() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try rebuilding the app?  and do you see any form of overloaded add method at all?

Comment: contact.class extends v4.app.Fragment or Fragment?You should extends v4.app.Fragment .

Comment: Can you put the code of contact.java here including its imports .

Comment: @PirateApp Can you explain a bit more rebuild app? I haven't overloaded anything because I literally just started a new project with a tabbed activity and added the fragment when the error came.

Comment: @tinysunlight contact.class extends Fragment, when I replace it with extends v4.app.Fragment I get an error in which "v4" is turned red.

Comment: @AndroidDev I have added the contact.java to the main post ! :)

Comment: It's my fault.you should extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be extending the wrong Fragment type in the contact class.

Since you are calling getSupportFragmentManager(), you will need to add a support fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) instead of the normal fragment (android.app.Fragment). Try extending the support fragment in the contact class and see if that resolves the issue.

Try this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class contact extends Fragment {
...
}
```

Comment: Where does he say he is doing this already? I see he is importing the support fragment in his main activity, but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your contact.java ,replace following imports :

```
package org.zewde.futuristiclivewallpapers;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

With following one :

```
package org.zewde.futuristiclivewallpapers;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment ;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Comment: Still you are getting the issue ,put your problem here .

Comment: Thanks for reply, Benstorm answer has already worked for me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.MyFragment, new YourFragmentName())
    .commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you imported a version of the fragment class that is not compatible with getSupportFragment class.. Change:

from:
    import android.app.Fragment;
to:
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

I hope that works for you...

Comment: To me, you answer doesn't add anything to the current accepted answer.